# List comprehension not working when dynamically changing the list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Why these two code snippets produce different results? I assume list comprehension creates a new list rather than modifying its assigned variable.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
x = [2 + x[0:i] .dot(y[0:i]) for i in range(0, len(x))]

print(x) # returns [2, 3, 5, 8]

x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x[i] = 2 + x[0:i] .dot(y[0:i])
print(x) # returns [2, 4, 12, 48]
```

Comment: Yes, list comprehensions produce a new list. Why would you expect it to be destructive? Note that the returned list will be a regular python list rather than a numpy array.

Comment: Assignment to a variable *never modifies the object*. It seems you have an answer already... I don't understand why you posted a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first lines build a list comprehension (a temporary variable), and then change x after all of the computations are done.

Your loop-based version does a computation, changes x[0], and then returns to do the next computation.  **x** is now altered, so the input to the computation is different from what you had in the first example.

Try this another way, and you'll see the difference.  Add a **print(x)** *inside* the loop in your existing code for a good contrast.

```
x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
result = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    result[i] = 2 + x[0:i] .dot(y[0:i])
    print (x, result)
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the list on the fly using a list comprehension at all?

Comment: If you mean, can you make partial updates as your loop does, no.  That's not how a list comprehension works.  A comprehension builds a new object according to the given instructions.  Update or assignment is not part of the documented purpose.  An assignment statement *finishes* evaluating the right side before it makes the assignment to the variable on the left.

Answer (score 0):

In second attempt, you are using this `x[0:i]`, the same numpy array which you assigning through each iteration. That's why it's getting a different result.

Try something like this,

```
x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
x_ = x[:]
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x[i] = 2 + x_[0:i] .dot(y[0:i])
```

List comprehension will create an new array,